# Mobile Device Center and Background Fail

Tags: html, css, mobile, background, center

I have one background and one centered image in my page. Its HTML + CSS. 
It works fine in desktop browsers. But when I open it from an Android Device, I have two problems.

1- Background image dont fit the page.

2- My centered image looks like it has been zoomed in. In Portrait mode it looks ok but when I turn the device to landscape position, it doesnt fit the screen. My screen resolution is 1280x720, my image size is 954x604. It should fit but it doesn't. It simply looks bigger and can't see the top of the image.

Can anyone help?

[Here is the test page](http://tolgatoykoc.com/centertest/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Celline - Selin Sarpkan</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dispencere">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

body{
font-size:9px;
color:#666;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
background-image:url('../images/paper.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;}

.dispencere{
background-image:url('../images/main.png');
width:954px;
height:604px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-295px 0 0 -465px;
text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Can you post a preview from an android device of what's happening?

Comment: I assume it's overflowing on the top and bottom? You are rotating it 2 degrees, and without doing the math, that would likely account for the overflow (I would suspect anyways...)

Comment: Here are the screenshots:
http://tolgatoykoc.com/centertest/portrait.png
http://tolgatoykoc.com/centertest/landscape.png

Comment: I am not rotating anything, that was a test, I erased the code.

Comment: What happens if you set background-size: contain?

Comment: If I use "contain" I can't see the background image in desktop browsers. Man I wish for single-browser-world. :)